# How to apply pixi.js animation insert to the texture of babylon.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, 2d, pixi.js, babylonjs

I have a simple `pixi.js` animation:

```
var pixiRenderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer({context:engine._gl, view:engine.getRenderingCanvas()});
const stage = new PIXI.Container();
const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('https://i.imgur.com/XYtAXP4.png');
const man = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
PIXI.ticker.shared.add(delta => {stage.rotation -= 0.01 * delta;});
```

And I'm trying to insert this animation in `HtmlElementTexture` on `babylon.js`:

```
var plane = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreatePlane("plane", {size: 10});
var material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("material", scene);
material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.HtmlElementTexture("texture", pixiRenderer.extract.canvas(), {scene:scene, engine:scene.getEngine()});
plane.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
plane.material = material;
```

But I see the animation on `pixi.js` separately from the `babylon.js` plane.
How to apply `pixi.js` animation to the texture of `babylon.js` ?

All example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8L31j9pe/